# W3C Validator Error Caused By Bootstrap h1 class (h1 element as a top-level heading only)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Validator Error:

```
    Warning: Consider using the h1 element as a top-level heading only (all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools).
From line 80, column 6; to line 80, column 29
80">↩     <h1 class = "pull-left"><a hre
```

The code causing the error:

```
<h1 class = "pull-left"><a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="images/logo.png" alt = "Logo"></a></h1>
```

Any way to fix this validator error ? I tried to add Text and make it invisible using css, but it makes the logo image invisible too.

Comment: "Any way to fix this validator error" — It's a warning. Do what the recommendation says to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

From an SEO perspective there is only supposed to be one h1 per page, because an h1 is intended to serve as a top level heading for the entire page. Search engines look at the h1 to get an idea about what the page is about, and if there are multiple h1s you can be docked SEO points. As the error says, `all h1 elements are treated as top-level headings by many screen readers and other tools`.

See this thread: https://moz.com/community/q/how-will-it-effect-seo-to-have-multiple-h1-tags-on-a-page

Hiding it with CSS won't help because the validator is analyzing the content structure (HTML).

This a universal HTML issue, not restricted to Bootstrap.